# "git gui" in CentOS has TINY font

Tags: git, tcl, font-size, tk-toolkit

I just installed a clean CentOS 8 64-bit and installed git.  I bring up "git gui" and the text labels in the windows are EXTREMELY small, like 2 pixels tall.  The menus, commit message text, file list and diff box all look normal.

All the sub windows (like options, create branch, etc.) have the same problem.

I have a 1080p screen and running it in VMware Workstation.  Is this a problem with TK?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the bug report in TCL:

https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview/dccd82bdc70dc25bb6709a6c14880a92104dda43

The work-around is to edit /usr/share/tk8.6/ttk/fonts.tcl.  Change under the x11 section:

```
set F(size) -12
set F(ttsize) -10
set F(capsize) -14
set F(fixedsize) -12
```

to

```
set F(size) 12
set F(ttsize) -10
set F(capsize) -14
set F(fixedsize) -12
```

I don't know what the minus is there for, but it screws it up.  Fixing the other ones may help in other areas.

Comment: The negative font size is a _hack_ to use an absolute size in pixels. Which is all very well… until you run on a HighDPI screen. A misconfigured fontconfig/Xft system (libraries we depend on) can also cause problems.